# AVPlayer: how to "play" image instead of video?

Tags: swift, swiftui, avplayer

I'm working on a health/fitness app with video trainings and in some cases i wanna show static images instead of videos for some "static" exercises. I wonder if there is any way to "play" image instead of video by AVPlayer?

Or, probably, some simple way to convert an image into a video "on the fly"

That would save me lots of time/coding efforts as everything is already made for AVplayer, not for displaying uiImage.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible , So instead of searching for it make a `UICollectionView` , Add your Images and with the help of Timer , and make a Slideshow...

Comment: Sounds like you could create gifs and show them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image is separate from the video data, no you cannot. Instead, you could just add a UIImageView with the same frame as the AVPlayer and show/hide whichever one you need at that time. If the image is a frame from the video, you can try playing around with .step function on AVPlayer, something like:

```
videoPlayer.currentItem?.step(byCount: 1)
```

If you use an UIImageView and need several photos to loop, you can use the built in

```
imageView.animationImages = [arrayOfImages]
imageView.animationDuration = TimeInterval(Double(0.5) * Double([arrayOfImages.count])) //seconds * # images
imageView.startAnimating()
```